# How to remove application installed from source code

Tags: software-installation

I believe this is probably a simple or even stupid question, but I did not found an answer for I am a beginner of Ubuntu.

I installed my application by compiling and running the source code like:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Now, I realized what I installed is a newer and unstable version. So, I need to re-install a stable version which is a litte older. I have the source code ready in hand, then what should I do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually depends on the `Makefile` provided. Try running `make uninstall`. If you are lucky, this might work. Otherwise you get something like:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
```

In that case you can try running `make clean`, but that will most probably delete files from source directory only.

You might want to read more about [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and study the corresponding `Makefile` to see available options.